# Mocking Stripe and AWS APIs in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, selenium, integration-testing, stripe-payments

I have written Integration tests for an application built in CodeIgniter 2.x. The tests are a Selenium + PhpUnit combination.

So far, I have used test accounts of Stripe and Amazon within the application and obviously the tests use the same accounts. I was wondering how would i go about creating Mock objects for these APIs so that i can avoid live data creation/deletion.

For Stripe, i could not find any mocking library for PHP. So stubbing the responses and requests does seem to be a good option. But again, even if i use stubs in my tests in place of real data, the application during that certain integration test will still be needing correct information for it to pass.How do i tell the application to use fake data?

Also, i would like to know if it is generally a good idea to mock objects in integration tests i.e. within the context of web applications?

Answer (score 0):

This is a tool that Stripe themselves have developed for mocking Stripe.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock

It runs a server on your local machine that responds to API calls in s Stripe-like fashion. This would be something you could try for acceptance tests

For PHP Unit tests, you'd be better using something like [AspectMock](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock) - although config is a bit tricky. You can specify in advance what a call to a Stripe resource (e.g. \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey, or \Stripe\Customer::retrieve) is supposed to return without hitting the Stripe servers - and you can also test whether or not your application code tried to make these calls. You can also simulate failures to test that your application behaves properly if, say, Stripe is down.